# EF6 Check each entity for changes before saving

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

This is an update method. Fromt eh view, the user can change data for an existing student, teacher or subject.

I return a view model to a controller that is made up of these 3 different entities:

-- Viewmodel --

```
public class StudentTeacherVM
{
    public StudentModel Student { get; set; }
    public TeacherModel Teacher { get; set; }
    public SubjectModel Subject { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller I split out the data in the VM into the db entities, then save them:

```
        using (var db = new SchoolEntities())
        {
            Student student = new Student()
            {
                StudentId = model.StudentId,
                FirstName = model.FirstName,
                LastName = model.LastName,
                EmailAddress = model.StudentEmailAddress,
                TeacherId = model.TeacherId
            };

            Teacher teacher = new Teacher()
            {
                TeacherId = model.TeacherId,
                FirstName = model.FirstName,
                LastName = model.LastName,
                EmailAddress = model.TeacherEmailAddress
                SubjectId = model.SubjectId
            };

            Subject subject = new Subject()
            {
                SubjectId = model.SubjectId,
                Description = model.SubjectDescription,
                Level = model.SubjectLevel
            };

            db.Entry(subject).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.Entry(teacher).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Sometimes one or more of the subjects are not modified, so when the code gets to this step it throws the "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)" error.

How do I check each entity for changes before doing the save, so I can skip an entity if there is no change?

Comment: The exception you are getting is not thrown when the entity is not changed, but when the entity is new and has to be added.

Comment: I think you need to add them to a DbSet rather than manually messing with the change state but I don't know a lot about your application.

Comment: Casey - What do mean by "add them to a DbSet" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check the entities for changes, you need to query them so the following solution maybe satisfying for you:

If you query the entities and then modify them then the change tracker will do this automatically for you and you do not have to write code for this. So you can use the following code:

```
    using (var db = new SchoolEntities())
    {
        Student student = db.students.Single(x => x.StudentId == model.StudentId);
        student.FirstName = model.FirstName;
        student.LastName = model.LastName;
        student.EmailAddress = model.StudentEmailAddress;
        student.TeacherId = model.TeacherId;

        Teacher teacher = db.teachers.Single(x => x.TeacherId == model.TeacherId);
        teacher.FirstName = model.FirstName;
        teacher.LastName = model.LastName;
        teacher.EmailAddress = model.TeacherEmailAddress;
        teacher.SubjectId = model.SubjectId;

        Subject subject = db.subjects.Single(x => x.SubjectId == model.SubjectId);
        subject.Description = model.SubjectDescription;
        subject.Level = model.SubjectLevel;

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Entities will be updated only if any property has been modified.